# Changing int value from a class function

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a shape class that I initialize from my `main` program and give the parameters in the constructor.

`Shape *cusomShape = new CustomShape(float radius, float origin)`

The shape class has some functions such as rollover and more. 
When the rollover function inside the shape class is fired, I want to change a certain `int` value in the `main` program. This might similar to firing of an event that changes the value when the rollover function is fired, but I am not sure how to do that in C++. If at all, events is the ideal approach here, it would great to see a short example coming.

If using the event is not the correct, what would the ideal way to go about this?

Comment: why are you using `float` instead of default `double`? why are you allocating the shape dynamically? how can you talk about an event handler in your class being "fired", and be unsure about how to do events in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is to pass a value by pointer or reference to the function in Shape and then modify it. If the function is called not from main but from somewhere else passing the pointer is the better option you have. First pass the pointer to the class and store it using another method and then each time rollover is called make use of it.

EDIT: example:

```
class CustomShape {

void storePointer(int* _value) {
  value = _value;
}

void rollover() {
  .. do stuff
  *value++; // for instance
  ... do stuff
}
int * value;
}


int main() {
  int a;

  CustomShape cs;
  cs.storePointer(&a);

  ....
  cs.rollover();
  ....
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Passing by reference because using observer pattern would be an overkill here?

Comment: I think so. Depends on what exactly you want to do, but if it is only what I show in my example, this should be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a reference to the variable in the constructor and save that reference. Change the value when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a reference to the variable to the member function that needs to change its value. Storing a reference in a class couples the Shape class to the reference. This means that each time you want to use the Shape, without updating the integer, you cannot, since the Shape constructor will expect a reference/pointer to the int as an argument (the Shape class will store the pointer/reference as an attribute). Passing a reference/pointer to the member function promotes **Low Coupling**.

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape
{
    double shapeValue_;

    public: 
        Shape (double value)
            : 
                shapeValue_(value)
        {}

        void fireFunction(int& updateMe)
        {
            updateMe = 123;
        }
};

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int update; 

    cout << update << endl;

    Shape s(4.5); 

    s.fireFunction(update); 

    cout << update << endl;

    return 0; 
};
```

And in this case, you have an option for a main program that doesn't involve shape object calling on fireFunction:

```
int main()
{
    Shape s(4.5); 

    // Main program that doesn't use fireFunction.

    return 0;
};
```

In this case, if you have member functions changing input arguments, you should take on a style for defining such functions: e.g. make sure that the variable that gets changed by the member function is always the first input argument in its declaration.

If you want complex objects to communicate updates between each other, you can make use of the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).